# React Native Uploading Video to YouTube (Stuck at Processing)

Tags: react-native, youtube-api

I am attempting to upload video files to YouTube using their v3 API and their MediaUploader. It works in my ReactJS application, but not in my React Native application. When uploading via React Native, the upload completes, then stalls at 100%. In my YouTube account, I can see the new video file, but it is stuck at "Video is still being processed."

I believe the issue may be that I need to send a video *file* and not an object with a video *uri* but I don't know how to get around that.

I am using the YouTube MediaUploader from the CORS example at https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/cors_upload.js I am using an OAuth 2.0 client Id, and this setup works correctly when using the ReactJS app via my website. I am using React Native Expo with Camera, which returns me an Object with a URI, for example:

Video File:  Object {
  "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/353A7969-E2A8-4C80-B641-C80B2B029555/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540dj_walksalot%252Fwandereo/Camera/E971DFEC-AB3E-4B6D-892F-9027AFE47A1A.mov",
}

This file can be viewed in the application, and I can even successfully send this to my server for playback on the web app and in the React Native app. However, sending this object in the MediaUploader does not work. It will take an appropriate amount of time to upload, but then sits at 100%, while my YouTube account will show it has received the video with the correct metadata, but the video itself remains stuck at "Video is still being processed."

video_file:  Object {
  "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/353A7969-E2A8-4C80-B641-C80B2B029555/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540dj_walksalot%252Fwandereo/Camera/E971DFEC-AB3E-4B6D-892F-9027AFE47A1A.mov",
}

```
export const uploadToYouTube = (access_token, video_file, metadata) => async (dispatch) => {
...cors_upload...

var uploader = new MediaUploader({
baseUrl: `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&key=API_KEY`,
file: video_file,
token: access_token,
metadata: metadata,
contentType: 'video/quicktime', 
// contentType: 'application/octet-stream',//"video/*",
// contentType = options.contentType || this.file.type || 'application/octet-stream';
params: {
   part: Object.keys(metadata).join(',')
},

onError: function(data) {
  // onError code
  let err = JSON.parse(data);
  dispatch(returnErrors(err.message, err.code))
  console.log('Error: ', err);
},

onProgress: function(progressEvent){
  // onProgress code
  let percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
  dispatch({
    type: UPLOAD_PROGRESS,
    payload: percentCompleted
  });
},

onComplete: function(data) {
  console.log('Complete');
   // onComplete code
  let responseData = JSON.parse(data);
  dispatch({
    type: UPLOAD_YOUTUBE_VIDEO,
    payload: JSON.parse(data)
  })
  dispatch({
    type: UPLOAD_PROGRESS,
    payload: 0
  });
}
```

});

uploader.upload();
}

Similar to my currently-working web app, after completing the upload, the "onComplete" function should fire, and YouTube should process the video. This does not happen. I believe it's because I'm attaching an object with a URI and not the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this from a post at Expert Mill by Joe Edgar at https://www.expertmill.com/2018/10/19/using-and-uploading-dynamically-created-local-files-in-react-native-and-expo/

By using fetch and .blob() I was able to convert the URI object to a data object and upload. Additional code:

const file = await fetch(video_file.uri);
const file_blob = await file.blob();

No need to install RNFetchBlob since this is in the Expo SDK.